# Understanding visibility: collapse on table column according to W3C documentation

Tags: css, css-tables, w3c

From W3C's [Dynamic rows and column effects](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#dynamic-effects)

> This collapse value causes the entire row or column to be removed from the display, and the space normally taken up by the row or column to be made available for other content.

From above what I understand is that if I do something like the snippet below, the result should be something like:

[image]

But instead it shows like:

[image]

```css
table tr td {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

/* All the below don't work as well. */

table tr td:first-child {
  visibility: collapse;
}

table colgroup col {
  visibility: collapse;
}

table colgroup {
  visibility: collapse;
} 

/* Works but I am trying to understand the why the column doesn't work as 
intended */
/* table tr {
  visibility: collapse;
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="red">
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 11</td>
      <td>Data 12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>Should show below the header row</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

#### Note

I have also tried applying collapse to `table tr td:first-child`, `table colgroup` and `table colgroup col` but to no avail. However, if I apply collapse on `table tr` then the paragraph shows at the top of the page as expected.

Additionally, I know I can achieve the intended result with `display: none;`, but I am trying to instead figure out if I am misunderstanding something from the doc. Additionally, I have tried the code on Chrome, Firefox and Edge, and the result is same on all.

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3x6rfbo/5)

Answer (score 0):

Hello @ZerosAndOnes you are applying `visibility: collapse;` to `td`. but you need to apply this property to `tr`.

> `visibility: collapse` for `table` rows, columns, column groups, and row groups, the row(s)
>   or column(s) are hidden and the space they would have occupied is
>   removed (as if display: none were applied to the column/row of the
>   table). However, the size of other rows and columns is still
>   calculated as though the cells in the collapsed row(s) or column(s)
>   are present. This value allows for the fast removal of a row or column
>   from a table without forcing the recalculation of widths and heights
>   for the entire table.

```css
table tbody tr {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="red">
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 11</td>
      <td>Data 12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>Should show below the header row</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, the quote reads "visibility: collapse for table rows, `columns`, column groups, and row groups, the row(s) or `column(s)`", from what I understand from this line is that it should work on td too. Regarding tr, I have already mentioned it in the questions note.

Comment: no @ZerosAndOnes it does not apply to `td`. `td` is table cell.

Comment: Why doesn't it work on `colgroup` or `col` then?
https://jsfiddle.net/m3x6rfbo/3/

Comment: it work on firefox but there is bug no chorme  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174167

Comment: Which version of firefox? I have tried the various selectors in https://jsfiddle.net/m3x6rfbo/5/ but still the paragraph doesn't adjust its position. I have tried it on 59.0.3 and 60.0.1. Additionally, the bug is about rows and columns. For row it's working fine even on chrome, as already mentioned.

Comment: firefox 56.0.1 @ZerosAndOnes

Comment: Tested it on 56.0.1 as well, the visibility is not collapsing but is rather hidden for col/colgroup/td. It collapses for tr though.

Comment: Yes it only Work in table row.