# Are there known issues when collapsing table rows instead of cells?

Tags: html, css, html-table

With css `visibility` property you can set it to `collapse` on certain table rows.
However there are two ways to achieve this. One is to place the logic on `<tr>`:

```
thead > tr {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

another is place the logic on individual cells:

```
thead > th {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

Are there any potential problems associated with these two ways?

Comment: I have, in unusual circumstances, used `display: none` on `<td>`s without issue.  (In my case, a JavaScript expected a certain number of cells and got confused by `colspan`; so I added a "spacer" cell, then hid it via CSS.)

Answer (score 0):

The `collapse` value of the `visibility` property is explicitly *for* table rows, columns, column groups, and row groups. You cannot (or at least shouldn't) use it on other, interior elements, since `hidden` is applied by the browser anyway. (A cell is not a [column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col).)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Therefore, the question is moot.

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423235/understanding-visibility-collapse-on-table-column-according-to-w3c-documentatio)

Comment: With rows you can apply it on `<tr>`s, but with columns you HAVE to apply on interior elements, such as `<th>` or `<td>`. How is the question moot?

Comment: See the answers and comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423235/understanding-visibility-collapse-on-table-column-according-to-w3c-documentatio. A cell is not a column.

Comment: ok, so it should be applied to column, but there is no `<tr>` equivalent for columns, is it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col

Comment: Chrome has a bug where it doesn't support visibility:collapse on columns and treats it as visibility:hidden.

Comment: @dgrogan, a supporting resource link is customary with a statement like that.